# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavresample.so.3

Tags: ffmpeg

After installing `FFmpeg-3.1.2` in `Ubuntu 12.04` following [the guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/ffmpeg.html) with no errors, I run `ffmpeg` and get the following error:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavresample.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Before installation, I delete every file in system path related to the previous ffmpeg library.
Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configure of `FFmpeg 3.1.2` is kind of "stupid".
I add `--enable-avresample` option and it works fine.
Since `FFmpeg` needs the module, why not enable it by default?

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu:

- if libavresample.so.3 is present in FFmpeg folder, please follow below steps:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install locate
3. locate libavresample.so.3
4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/neoastra/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/libswresample/libswresample.so.3
5. sudo ldconfig